# Using JQuery to render result in Flask app

Tags: jquery, flask

Up to now i managed to create a page with a text field and a button. Once the user enters a text and clicks the button, the result of a search (database) is shown both in the console and in the command prompt. I need the code to be shown the result in an empty `<div id='empty'>`

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['POST'])
def search():
name =  request.form['name'];
j=CARDS_COLLECTION.find({'name':"whatever"})
for k in j:
    print k
print name
return json.dumps({'status':'OK','name':name});


@app.route('/page')
def page():
return render_template('page.html')
```

This is the script on the page.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(function() {
$('button').click(function() {
    var name = $('#txtname').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/search',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
});</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the result inside a "div" you should execute javascript inside of the ajax function, inside of success function. See an example of what you have to do.

# app.py
    from flask import Flask, request, render_template,jsonify

```
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/search', methods=['POST'])
def search():
    # this works and I don't know  why because we should use
    # request.get_json() to parse json data...
    name = request.form['name']
    # using the jsonify function to turn dict into json and send
    # the correct HTTP header
    return jsonify({"status": "OK", "name": name}), 200


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template("search.html")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and the html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<input id="search_field" type="text">
<button>Search!!</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('button').click(function() {
    // we dont use form because we wanna send data with javascript
    // so we get the value of input into a variable
    var name_field = $("#search_field").val();
    // I wanna send the data as json documento, so we create one to put our    values
    var my_data = {
        name: name_field
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "/search",
        data: my_data,  // here come the json data
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
            // I said that you must use parseJSON but I was wrong
            // because the data is already a JSON document and try to
            // parse it again leads to an error... so, don't use it for now
            // more details http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/
            // var data = $.parseJSON(response);

            // just to see what is comming from server
            console.log(response);

            // now we will create a div above every element on body
            // notice that I'm escaping the " for id... there are many ways and methods
            // to insert html or text, aways depends on your needs.
            $('body').prepend("<div id=\"empty\">"+response.name+"</div>");
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unless i misunderstood something, your code is inserting on the page the same text the user entered in the field. I need it to insert on the page the result of the search performed in the /search function. @xFilipe

Comment: The code is inserting inside of a div tag, to insert the div itself you must use the append function or something like... Show me more details about the code and where it should be inserted so I can make it for you

Comment: I managed to edit your code, the search function is like this now:
@app.route('/search', methods=['POST'])
def search():
 temp=[]
 name =  request.form['name'];
 j=CARDS_COLLECTION.find({'functionalname': {'$regex': name.lower()}},{"_id":1, "url":1, "name":1, 'sets':1, 'functionalname':1})
 name=""
 for k in j:
  name=name+str(k)
  
 return json.dumps({'status':'OK','name':name});

Comment: now, when i click the button, it returns something like this:
{u'url': u'url1', u'_id': ObjectId('123'), u'functionalname': u'm1', u'name': u'm1', u'sets': [u'abc', u'def']}{u'url': u'url2', u'_id': ObjectId('124'), u'functionalname': u'm2', u'name': u'm2', u'sets': [u'ghj']}

(note that each item is surrounded by {}, so i guess that's not appropriate, is it?) @xFilipe

Comment: Hi David, sorry I could not answer you yesterday... I changed my answer, see if it helps you now...